# Log in with cURL and make an other request with cURL after

Tags: php, post, curl, request, sleep

I have a problem with my requests with cURL.

I want to log-in, it works. I want to conserve the cookie to keeep the connexion available, it works.

```
$lien = 'https://thewebsite.com';
$postfields = array(
    'username' => 'test123',
    'password' => 'test123'
);

$path_cookie = 'connexion.txt';
if (!file_exists(realpath($path_cookie))) touch($path_cookie);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lien);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($path_cookie));

$return = curl_exec($curl);

echo($return);
curl_close($curl);
```

**Second part :**

```
$lien2 = 'https://thewebsite.com/myaccount';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $lien2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($path_cookie));

$return = curl_exec($curl); 

echo realpath($path_cookie);
curl_close($curl);
```

But when I want to make an other requests, it won't work, the output is :

> **Object moved to here.**

*Here* is the page of the login (https://thewebsite.com)  ...

So the connexion doesn't stay available and the server has been kicked out when I try to achieve the second curl command.

Any one can help me please?

*Maybe the first request isn't complete before the second one, how can I make a pause between the 2 requests? (sleep won't work)*

Comment: Maybe the first request is not complete when the second is executed ... sleep(10) won't work to make a "pause" between the 2, maybe some one have an idea?

Comment: Or maybe the session isn't "on" when i try the second request ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION:
>
> TRUE to mark this as a new cookie "session". It will force libcurl to ignore all cookies it is about to load that are "session cookies" from the previous session. By default, libcurl always stores and loads all cookies, independent if they are session cookies or not. Session cookies are cookies without expiry date and they are meant to be alive and existing for this "session" only.

So in other words, remove `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` from your `second part` code and your code should work.